# Get the number of days using joda-time in Grails

Tags: grails, jodatime, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I need to get the number of days between two dates. That's why I have installed joda-time-1.5 version. I am using grails-2.4.2. I have googled for it but there is example for joda-time with Java. I have not found any grails-joda-time example. I am using java-1.7.

For some reason I cannot use java-1.8. That's why I installed joda-time. But as suggested in the example with Java there is class named Days and LocalDate which I can't find in the grails joda-time plugin.

I need to do it perfectly such as with leap-year.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in Stack Overflow:

```
public static long getDifferenceDays(Date d1, Date d2) {
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I added (1) with the result to add current day. Otherwise it gives result also for leap-year.